# Pronunciation of "off" in a particular case

Tags: pronunciation

I was wondering how should I pronounce "off" in the sentence below:

> Can't take my eyes off you.

Do we pronounce the "f" twice ?

NB : is there a general rule ?

Comment: Was your "particular case" the song *Can't Take My Eyes Off You*?

Comment: I ask this because different singers sing this line differently in the song, with or without *of*. So even if you have lyrics which say *Can't take my eyes off you*, the singer (probably most of them) may actually be singing *can't take my eyes off of you*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can't take my eyes **off** you.

*off* only has the sound of one "f". Maybe what you heard was:

> Can't take my eyes **off of** you.

When you say *off of* quickly, the "f" in *of* sounds like an extra "f" added to the "f sound in *off*. So "ff" sound (or possibly "fv" I suppose).

Comment: I doubt that "off of" is more proper. Consider https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off_of.

Comment: I take (at)user3169's use of **proper** is to mean the more **usual use** of the phrase, popularise by Frankie Valli and the Four Seasons in their 1967 hit [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGFToiLtXro). A **fantastic** song!   *Can't take my eyes off you** can be the opposite of **I'll keep an eye on you**

Comment: @laugh Sorry that was a poor description. I edited it.

Comment: @Peter "I'll keep an eye on you" is not opposite, but more like spying on or watching someone without being noticed. Opposite might be "I can't stand to look at you."

Comment: @GoDucks OK I'll drop the matter.

Answer (score 3):

A single "f" sound. Note that it's different from the "v" sound in *of*.